# Imports are now case sensitive?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-cli

Today I've started migrating an existing Angular app to the latest version `4.4.6`. I'm trying to use `debounceTime` operator to discard some values between a specified time. Here's what the code looks like:

```js
this.filtro.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap(() => ...);
```

After building it with the `--dev` flag (Angular CLI), I've started getting an error which says that `debounceTime` is not a function. After some digging, I've noticed that I was improting debounceTime through this statement:

```js
import "rxjs/add/operator/debouncetime";
```

Changing `debouncetime` to `debounceTime` solved the issue, but I'm curious about this change. Is this documented anywhere? Was the previous behavior wrong?

Comment: Were you importing debounceTime anywhere else?

Comment: Nop. Just on that file.

Comment: what version of rxjs do you use now and used before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imports are *always* case-sensitive.

Even though case-insensitive imports may work on case-insensitive OSes (Windows) due to the way how file system works, this is a mistake that will result in bugs (modules which names are different in case can be treated as different modules) and will have problems on other OSes. The same applies to native ES modules and case-insensitive URLs.

The proper import is:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime";
```

Comment: @LefiTarik That's correct, FS can be case-insensitive on Mac too, this is configurable.